# How can I generate a HMAC key and secret key and share with client using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac, amazon-kms, hardware-security-module

I am looking to generate a HMAC key and secret value as I want to use it as part of API request signatures. I want to be able to share the secret value and key with a 3rd party so I need access the value in plain text for one time. There would be a HMAC per 3rd party so the number could be large.

Option 1, I could generate this application side but I don't want to store in the dB and I was hoping to use a aws for storage but unsure what the process would be?

Option 2, Preferably I wanted to use AWS to generate the key and secret for HMAC as it can ensure uniqueness etc. I wanted it to provide the key and the secret one time. Looking at the documentation it seems to suggest that the secret value never leaves the HSM. Is my understanding correct or what is the best way to implement this using AWS?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

From reading the docs it seems to me that the only way is to generate the key outside KMS and then import it into KMS.

Did you find a better solution?